# Mix and match Coroutines and Rxjava

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, kotlin-coroutines

`Coroutines and RxJava3`

I have the following method that first makes a call to a suspend method and in the same launch scope I make 2 calls to RxJava.

I am wondering if there is a way to remove the Rxjava code out of the `viewModelScope.launch` scope and return the result of `fetchRecentUseCase.execute()`.

Basically, is it possible for the `viewModelScope.launch` to return the `listOfProducts` rather than doing everything in the launch scope?

```
fun loadRecentlyViewed() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val listOfProducts = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            fetchRecentUseCase.execute()
        }

        val listOfSkus = listOfProducts.map { it.sku }

        if (listOfSkus.isNotEmpty()) {
            loadProductUseCase.execute(listOfSkus)
                .subscribeOn(schedulersFacade.io)
                .flatMap(convertProductDisplayUseCase::execute)
                .map { /* work being done */ }
                .observeOn(schedulersFacade.ui)
                .subscribeBy(
                    onError = Timber::e,
                    onSuccess = { }
                )
        }
    }
}
```

Usecase for the suspend method

```
class FetchRecentUseCaseImp() {
    override suspend fun execute(): List<Products> {
        // Call to network 
    }
}
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly is the return type of `loadProductUseCase.execute`? You said you want to return the list of Product, but your code looks like it's mapping that List to Skus, and then doing another operation with Rx to convert them back to Products, maybe?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion I have edited the question. Basically, I want to return the result from the `viewModelScope.launch`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With coroutines, the way to return a single item that is produced asynchronously is to use a `suspend` function. So instead of launching a coroutine, you mark the function as `suspend` and convert blocking or async callback functions into non-blocking code.

The places where coroutines are launched are typically at UI interactions (click listeners), or when classes are first created (on Android, this is places like in a ViewModel constructor or Fragment's `onViewCreated()`).

As a side note, it is against convention for any `suspend` function to expect the caller to have to specify a dispatcher. It should internally delegate if it needs to, for example:

```
class FetchRecentUseCaseImp() {
    override suspend fun execute(): List<Products> = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        // Synchronous call to network 
    }
}
```

But if you were using a library like Retrofit, you'd simply make your Request and `await()` it without specifying a dispatcher, because `await()` is a suspend function itself.

So your function should look something like:

```
suspend fun loadRecentlyViewed(): List<SomeProductType> {
  val listOfSkus = fetchRecentUseCase.execute().map(Product::sku)
  if (listOfSkus.isEmpty()) {
    return emptyList()
  }
  return runCatching {
    loadProductUseCase.execute(listOfSkus) // A Single, I'm assuming
      .await() // Only if you're not completely stripping Rx from project
      .map { convertProductDisplayUseCase.execute(it).await() } // Ditto for await()
      .toList()
      .flatten()
  }.onFailure(Timber::e)
    .getOrDefault(emptyList())
}
```